# Complex Cube root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

If   $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity, then 
$cos [\{(1-\omega )(1-\omega^2 )+ ...+ (10-\omega )(10-\omega^2 )\}\frac{\pi}{900}]$

=$cos [\{\sum_{k=1}^{10}(k-\omega)(k-\omega^2)\} \frac {\pi}{900}]$

what is next step can't get it

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$\implies w^3=1\iff(w-1)(w^2+w+1)=0\implies w^2+w+1=0$ as $w\ne1$

$$(a-w)(a-w^2)=a^2+a+1$$

$$\implies\sum_{a=1}^n(a-w)(a-w^2)=\sum_{a=1}^na^2+\sum_{a=1}^na+\sum_{a=1}^n1$$

$$=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\dfrac{n(n+1)}2+n$$